# Create an object of type datetime64[ns] in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series like the one below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s = pd.Series(np.array([20201018, 20201019, 20201020]), index = [0, 1, 2])
s = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y%m%d')
print(s)
0   2020-10-18
1   2020-10-19
2   2020-10-20
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want to check if say the date 2020-10-18 is present in the series. If I do the below I get false.

```
date = pd.to_datetime(20201018, format='%Y%m%d')
print(date in s)
```

I guess this is due to the series containing the date in the type `datetime64[ns]` while the object I created is of type `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'. How can I go about checking if a date is present in such a series?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('2020-10-18') in s.values` would be another way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `date in s` will check for `date` in `s.index`. For example:

```
0 in s
```

returns `True` since `s.index` is `[0,1,2]`.

For this case, use comparison:

```
s.eq(date).any()
```

or, for several dates, use `isin`:

```
s.isin([date1, date2]).any()
```